# Join table only if record exists or return null?

Tags: postgresql, join, left-join

I am querying records from multiple tables. Records exist for any `id_value` in `schema.table_one` but may or may not exist in `schema.table_two` (or additional tables joined in the query).

The following query format works fine when there is a record with the given  `id_val` in all queried tables:

```
SELECT one.value_one, two.value_two
FROM schema.table_one one LEFT JOIN schema.table_two two 
    ON one.id_value = two.id_value 
    WHERE one.id_value = 'id_val' AND two.other_column = 'other_val';
```

If the record is removed from `table_two` or doesn't exist (and/or any additionally joined tables) then no results are returned.

Is there a way to either return null for `two.value_two` if there is no record for the given `id_val` in `table_two` or only join if the record exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move conditions relating to the second table from `WHERE` to `ON`:

```
SELECT one.value_one, two.value_two
FROM schema.table_one one 
LEFT JOIN schema.table_two two 
    ON one.id_value = two.id_value 
    AND two.other_column = 'other_val'
WHERE one.id_value = 'id_val'
```

Comment: Seems obvious now, I was overthinking it. Thanks!